# jQuery sort elements using data id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have an HTML structure as follows:

```
<div class="clist">
    <div data-sid=1></div>
    <div data-sid=2></div>
    <div data-sid=2></div>
    <div data-sid=1></div>
    <div data-sid=2></div>
    <div data-sid=2></div>
    <div data-sid=1></div>
</div>
```

I would like to sort them as:

```
<div class="clist">
    <div data-sid=1></div>
    <div data-sid=1></div>
    <div data-sid=1></div>
    <div data-sid=2></div>
    <div data-sid=2></div>
    <div data-sid=2></div>
    <div data-sid=2></div>
</div>
```

I am using the following function:

```
function sortContacts() {
    var contacts = $('div.clist'), cont = contacts.children('div');

    cont.detach().sort(function(a, b) {
        var astts = $(a).data('sid');
        var bstts = $(b).data('sid')
        return (astts > bstts) ? (astts > bstts) ? 1 : 0 : -1;
    });

    contacts.append(cont);
}
```

It is not working as expected.

It is working well for the first run but after adding new element or changing the `data-sid` attributes it no longer works.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f5mC9/1/

Not working?

Comment: i would like to swap elements

Comment: you could use tinysort (http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/)

Answer (score 81):

You can use `dataset` property which stores all of the custom `data-*` attributes of an element, it returns a string, in case that you want to convert the string to a number you can use `parseInt` or `+` operator.

```
$('.clist div').sort(function(a,b) {
     return a.dataset.sid > b.dataset.sid;
}).appendTo('.clist');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CFYnE/

And your own code also work: http://jsfiddle.net/f5mC9/

Edit: Please note that IE10! and below do not support the `.dataset` property, if you want to support all browsers you can use jQuery's `.data()` method instead:

```
$('.clist div').sort(function(a,b) {
     return $(a).data('sid') > $(b).data('sid');
}).appendTo('.clist');
```

Comment: Note that using `.data()` to access HTML data attributes creates a copy of the data attribute when it is first accessed. If you change the data attribute's value later on, `data()` will still return the old value.

Comment: I'm not getting ``.data()`` to work in IE11 or Edge. :( http://jsfiddle.net/4o771n7o/

Comment: @jimmykup - `.data()` works just fine in IE11 and Edge. It is the comparison which is different.

Comment: I ran into problems when sorting a list of more than 10 by a string value. I had to change the comparison to:

return a.dataset.sid > b.dataset.sid ? 1 : (a.dataset.sid < b.dataset.sid ? -1 : 0);

Comment: The attributes are retrieved as a string values. The way to sort them as numbers: `return +a.dataset.sid - +b.dataset.sid;`

Comment: @trincot That's a good point. It should be noted that jQuery `.data()` tries to parse the `data-*` attributes as JSON, so stringified numbers are coerced into real numbers by jQuery.

Comment: @Aaron that definitely solved the problems I've faced. But I could not understand why. Can you explain how your code solved that?

Answer (score 15):

```
$('.clist div').sort(function(a,b) {
     return parseInt(a.dataset.sid) - parseInt(b.dataset.sid);
}).appendTo('.clist');
```

Comment: How to reverse the sort so that it's descending?

Answer (score 6):

A more generic function to sort elements using jQuery:

```
$.fn.sortChildren = function (sortingFunction: any) {

    return this.each(function () {
        const children = $(this).children().get();
        children.sort(sortingFunction);
        $(this).append(children);
    });

};
```

Usage:

```
$(".clist").sortChildren((a, b) => a.dataset.sid > b.dataset.sid ? 1 : -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function orderSteps() {
    var steps = $('div.steps'),
        cont = steps.children('div.step');
    cont.detach().sort(function (a, b) {
        var astts = a;
        var bstts = b;

        // stripping the id to get the position number
        var classArrA = $(astts).attr("id").split("-")[1];
        var classArrB = $(bstts).attr("id").split("-")[1];

        // checking for the greater position and order accordingly
        if (parseInt(classArrA) > parseInt(classArrB)) {
            return (0)
        }
        else {
            return (-1)
        }
    })
    steps.append(cont);
};

orderSteps()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid steps">
            <div class="row text-center border-bottom step" id="step-1">
                <span class="col-3">Item 1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center border-bottom step" id="step-2">
                <span class="col-3">Item 2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center border-bottom step" id="step-30">
                <span class="col-3">Item 3</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center border-bottom step" id="step-4">
                <span class="col-3">Item 4</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```