# jQuery/Javascript - Sort Parent Divs Based on A number in Child Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say we have the following html div structure.

```
 <div class="article-container">

      <div class="article">
         <div class="article-child">views 9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
         <div class="article-child">views 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
         <div class="article-child">views 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
         <div class="article-child">views 10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
         <div class="article-child">views 1</div>
      </div>

 </div>
```

Using jQuery, how can I just clone/copy-paste the "article" divs in the ascending/descending order of the number coming in their children values. So I get result like this.

```
 <div class="article-container">

      <div class="article">
         <div class="article-child">views 10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
         <div class="article-child">views 9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
         <div class="article-child">views 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
         <div class="article-child">views 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="article">
         <div class="article-child">views 1</div>
      </div>

 </div>
```

I was trying to prepare algorithm for it before I code. I know how to code in jQuery and the copy paste stuff but I am not sure how would I achieve this.

Comment: Try to use  attribute instead of comparing with inner html

Comment: That would have been very easy if that was the case but really, the attributes aren't present in my case. I am presented with this exact situation.

Comment: so then extract the values of the children, safe the parent element in an array and then u can sort them as u want

Comment: How would I compare them?

Comment: safe them in an array like this array[ [value, parent], [value, parent]] this way you can compare their values

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490391/jquery-sort-elements-using-data-id this might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var cont = $(".article-container");
var arr = $.makeArray(cont.children(".article"));

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var textA = +$(a).find('.article-child').text();
  var textB = +$(b).find('.article-child').text();

  if (textA < textB) return 1;
  if (textA > textB) return -1;

  return 0;
});

cont.empty();

$.each(arr, function() {
    cont.append(this);
});
```

See **demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/msvpfg8k/2/)**

---

If you must consider the text, you should use a regexp:

```
var cont = $(".article-container");
var arr = $.makeArray(cont.children(".article"));

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var textA = +$(a).find('.article-child').text().match(/views (\d+)/)[1];
  var textB = +$(b).find('.article-child').text().match(/views (\d+)/)[1];

  if (textA < textB) return 1;
  if (textA > textB) return -1;

  return 0;
});

cont.empty();

$.each(arr, function() {
    cont.append(this);
});
```

See **demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/msvpfg8k/3/)**

Comment: This is a good approach. I am giving it a try. Will share the response here in a while. Thank you.

Comment: Please, read again, I've made a little fix to match exactly your sort order

Comment: This is exactly working for if I have numbers only on the child div. What if I have strings along with the numbers in the child elements. I guess we will have to use regex to get numbers out of it. Let me edit the question. And really very thankful to this help.