# Using .sort() and .data() to sort HTML elements in IE11 and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this question ([jQuery sort elements using data id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490391/jquery-sort-elements-using-data-id/13490529#13490529)) to get a lot of work done on a project I'm doing.

The top voted answer mentions that using jQuery;s `.data()` is required if I need it to work in IE10 and below. I haven't tested it in any of those browsers, but I have found that it does not work in IE11 or Edge.

Here's the jsfiddle that works just fine in Chrome for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4o771n7o/

**HTML**

```
<div class="clist">
    <div data-sid=1>1</div>
    <div data-sid=4>4</div>
    <div data-sid=3>3</div>
    <div data-sid=1>1</div>
    <div data-sid=4>4</div>
    <div data-sid=2>2</div>
    <div data-sid=1>1</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.clist div').sort(function(a,b) {
     return $(a).data('sid') > $(b).data('sid');
}).appendTo('.clist');
```

Comment: And that fails to work in IE11 and Edge?

Comment: Can you explain how it fails? As in does it not sort at all, is there an error message?

Comment: It doesn't sort at all for me. No error message in the console or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sort function is bad; I'm not sure why it works for any other browser. Working JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0m75k1fm/

The sort function should return a number, not a boolean:

```
$('.clist div').sort(function(a,b) {
     return parseInt($(a).data('sid'), 10) - parseInt($(b).data('sid'), 10);
}).appendTo('.clist');
```

Comment: Looks like IE can handle the missing quotes; it's just the sort function that is specifically tripping it up.

Comment: Basically you didn't change anything. Quotes are optional in this case and `>` handles to number conversion behind the scene.

Comment: The attributes are not malformed. Yes, changing it to subtract does help because the compareFunction expects an integer but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @dfsq: look carefully.

Comment: @TravisJ, it does answer the question; the sort function is completely wrong.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort for an explanation of sort functions.

Comment: @Jacob - While the sort function is not directly returning the proper type, it  has worked for a long time in this fashion. Perhaps if you got into why using the logical comparison is no longer working in this exact browser you would be getting closer.

Comment: @dfsq: Sort functions should return -1, 0, or 1 to indicate ordering. Just because JS can convert Boolean to Number doesn't mean the sort function is correct.

Comment: Yes, I agree about sorting returning number. Then `return $(a).data('sid') - $(b).data('sid');` should be enough. Anyway +1 for this, this might be the issue for IE.

Comment: Perhaps some browsers happen to succeed due to their specific sorting algorithm, but they're not _supposed_ to work with a sort function like that.

Comment: Thanks for this. Evgeny's answer worked for me as well. Marked this one as correct since the discussion in the comments gave me a good understanding of what was going on.

Comment: @dfsq - It is most certainly the issue for newer versions of IE. It would have been nice to see an explanation of *why* here though aside from just "do this" which is basically what is shown. There is no explanation given.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$('.clist div').sort(function(a,b) {
     return $(a).attr('data-sid') > $(b).attr('data-sid') ? 1 : -1;
}).appendTo('.clist');
```

[Works in edge](http://jsfiddle.net/4o771n7o/15/)

Comment: Did you test this in IE11 and Edge?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort HTML elements pretty easily without jQuery. Just use the built in `document.querySelectorAll` function to select your collection of HTML elements (as a nodelist) and then use the built in `Array.prototype.sort.apply(YourCollection,[SortFunction])` to invoke the Array object's `sort` function on your nodeList.

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".clist [data-sid]");

Array.prototype.sort.apply(nodes,
[function(first, second) {
    var a = +first.getAttribute("data-sid"),
      b = +second.getAttribute("data-sid");
    return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
  }]);

for (i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
  document.querySelector(".clist").appendChild(nodes[i]);
}
```

```css
[data-sid] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
[data-sid="1"] {
  background-color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
}
[data-sid="2"] {
  background-color: rgb(255, 200, 200);
}
[data-sid="3"] {
  background-color: rgb(255, 100, 100);
}
[data-sid="4"] {
  background-color: rgb(255, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<div class="clist">
  <div data-sid=1>1</div>
  <div data-sid=4>4</div>
  <div data-sid=3>3</div>
  <div data-sid=1>1</div>
  <div data-sid=4>4</div>
  <div data-sid=2>2</div>
  <div data-sid=1>1</div>
</div>
```